# Open original file from local website via Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, editor, firebug

For local websites work in Ubuntu. I try to open files with my editor (gedit) through Firebug's *HTML* and *CSS* panel.

In the editor configuration (Firebug button > *Open With Editor* > *Configure Editors...*) I can set the argument `%file`, but that opens a temporary copy of the file.

Though I want to open the original one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently (with Firebug 2.0.7) not possible.

There is an [enhancement request for this in Firebug's issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5035). Though the upcoming version [Firebug 3 will integrate into the Firefox DevTools](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/11/10/firebug-3-next-generation-of-firebug/) and moved to the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next/issues), so you may want to request the feature there again.

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually no news about implementation in the request post linked.

Comment: URL mapping obviously didn't have high priority. I've updated my answer to refer to the new issue tracker Firebug is using.